# seperate Tstringlist in Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, tstringlist

I want to separate a string list by events, see below list.

```
Event: DialBegin
Privilege: call,all
Channel: PJSIP/1177-00000638
ChannelState: 4
ChannelStateDesc: Ring
CallerIDNum: 1177
CallerIDName: IT Test

// Seperation //

Event: NewConnectedLine // New Seperation
Privilege: call,all
Channel: PJSIP/1177-00000638
ChannelState: 4
ChannelStateDesc: Ring
CallerIDNum: 1177
CallerIDName: IT Test

// Seperation //

Event: ....
```

Currently I get the names of the events with NameValueSeparator(),

```
Eventlst.Text := StrBuffer;
Eventlst.NameValueSeparator := ':';
str := Trim(Eventlst.Values['Event']);
// result: Dialbegin
```

but I can not get the other event 'NewConnectedLine' and the other which follows either.

Can someone please help me with the solution?

Comment: the name/value functionality is not made for multiple keys with the same name. Just process the stringlist line per line and search for event with ContainsStr() for example

Comment: You can actually use the name/value construct for that, but you have to iterate the list anyway. You can then use `Names[index]` to get the name of a line, and `ValueFromIndex[index]` to get its value. So you can't get all items by name, but you can let the stringlist help you split the name from the value. But given the scenario, I don't think it will do you much good. Maybe online to read the file line by line and storing those in a stringlist. Then you can parse a single event using the stringlist, clear it, and continue reading the file until the next separator.

Comment: Parsing files is not a job for string lists. Read the file line by line.